# Can I use MySQL interactively from an SQL block in org-mode?

Tags: mysql, sql, emacs, org-mode

I use R interactively from Org-mode - the keybinding `C-x '` from within an R code-block launches an interactive R session using ESS.

When I press `C-x '` from inside an SQL code block, it sends the code block to an SQL-mode buffer, but it is not clear how I can then send a query to MySQL.

Can I do this with MySQL?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772032/configuring-custom-groups-in-my-cnf, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5734965/199217

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, include the code from the accepted answer to [How can I get emacs sql-mode to use the mysql config file (.my.cnf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734965/how-can-i-get-emacs-sql-mode-to-use-the-mysql-config-file-my-cnf) in your `.emacs`

Second, use `C-x '` from within the SQL code block to send the code block to an SQL mode buffer

Once the code block has been sent to a buffer in SQL mode, launch your MySQL session using `M-x pool-a` (or whatever connection you wish to use).

At this point, the standard SQL keybindings can be used:

```
C-c C-c send paragraph
C-c C-r send selected region
C-c C-b send entire buffer
C-c C-s send string
```